# Split JavaScript variable's string content and assign to separate JS vars

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have a JS var that holds string whose content is like this `Automated - UI & Functional Regression on iPhone 6 running iOS 9`. Similarly I have other string values as:

```
Automated - Under the Hood: iPhone 6 running iOS 9  

Automated - AU/NZ:  iPhone 6 running iOS 9

Automated - DRM: iPhone 6 running iOS 9 

Automated - Ads regression: iPhone6 running iOS 9

Automated - Ads regression: iPhone 5 running iOS 8 

Automated - UI & Functional Regression on iPad 2 running iOS 8

Automated - Under the Hood: iPad Air on iOS 8

Automated - AU/NZ: iPad Air running iOS 8

Automated - DRM iPadAir running iOS 8
```

---

Here is JS var:

```
var dump = test.name //test.name = "Automated - UI & Functional........"
```

How do I fetch the specific content in this dump var such as `UI & Functional`, `iPhone 6`, `iOS`, `9` and assign each of them to different var further and finally print? Here 9 is the OS version.

Idea is to print eventually in JS as:

```
Type: UI & Functional regression
Phone: iPhone 6
OS: iOS 
OS version: 9
```

Similarly for other above mentioned strings.

What I tried or can think of:

1. Use the JS split() function

2. Is it possible to put the var string content in an array and then split()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
    var arystrFields = test.split("-")
       ,strAfterAutomated = arystrFields[1].trim();
```

You need a more rigid format for the string to extract things further, use a delimiter such as : to split the other fields, then you could do this to split the remaining fields:

```
    var arystrRemaining = arystrFields[1].split(":");
```

Comment: Not sure if I get that: Let's say, I have test var as `var test = "Automated - Under the Hood: iPhone 6 running iOS 9"` **only**. For this example, I want to have output as `Type: Under the Hood` then on next line `Phone: iPhone 6` then on next line `OS type: iOS` then on next line `OS version: 9`.

Comment: Nvm, got this - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it to use regex. Look this plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/Thk5j4ZqxSklTKTubQ40?p=preview

There is two simple regex :

```
var test = 'Automated - Under the Hood: iPhone 6 running iOS 9 \n\r' +
           'Automated - AU/NZ:  iPhone 6 running iOS 9\n\r' +
           'Automated - DRM: iPhone 6 running iOS 9\n\r' +
           'Automated - Ads regression: iPhone6 running iOS 9\n\r' +
           'Automated - Ads regression: iPhone 5 running iOS 8\n\r' +
           'Automated - UI & Functional Regression on iPad 2 running iOS 8\n\r' +
           'Automated - Under the Hood: iPad Air on iOS 8\n\r' +
           'Automated - UI & Functional Regression on iPad 2 running iOS 9\n\r' +
           'Automated - AU/NZ: iPad Air running iOS 8\n\r' +
           'Automated - DRM iPadAir running iOS 8\n\r';

var reg = /Automated - UI & Functional Regression on(.*)/;

var lines = test.split('\n\r')

console.log(lines);
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var regResult = reg.exec(lines[i]);
  if(regResult && regResult[1]) {
    console.log(lines[i], 'ok');
    result.push(regResult[1]);
  }
  else {
    console.log(lines[i], 'nok');
  }
}

console.log(result);

var regSecond = /(.*)running ([A-Za-z]*) ([0-9])/

var lstResult = []
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  var splitted = regSecond.exec(result[i]);
  console.log(splitted);
  lstResult.push({
    Phone: splitted[1].trim(),
    OS: splitted[2].trim(),
    'OS version': splitted[3].trim()
  })
}
```

console.log(lstResult);

Maybe regex must be more complex to get all case

Comment: There are few syntax errors such as not ending few declarations by `;`. I assumed this is an example and I was looking at the plunker - maybe we can collaborate there. `Plunker link` has a non working code.

Comment: Let's say, I have test var as `var test = "Automated - Under the Hood: iPhone 6 running iOS 9"` **only**. For this example, I want to have output as `Type: Under the Hood` then on next line `Phone: iPhone 6` then on next line `OS type: iOS` then on next line `OS version: 9`.

Comment: Nvm, I fixed all the things.

Answer (score 0):

You can first use split on your string :

`var x = dump.split(":");`

This will give you an array of 2 items and the first 1 will be the type. Next you can take the second item of the array and split it on space. Then you can combine the new array that you get to make the new items . For example:

`var phone = secondArray[0] + secondArray[1]; 
 var os =  secondArray[3];`

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the text using `test.split(' ');` & store the result in an array. That way you will have everything separated & stored in its own var.